# PHP downloading excel file blank using frames

Tags: javascript, php, excel

I have a frame with a header containing some buttons (list, pdf and excel). Under the header it lists data from db. It works fine with listing option but when I try to download excel file it comes blank with the following message:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/force-download

I've searched through the internet and tried some other functions but nothing has helped.

php:

frames.php

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<frameset  bordercolor="#3399CC" rows="30,*">
    <frame name="header" id="header" src="header.php" scrolling="no" noresize>
    <frame name="List" id="List">
<noframes>
</html>
<body style="margin:0px;">
</body>
</html>
</noframes>
</frameset>
```

ranking.php

```
if ($tp==4){ // tp 4 is from excel button option
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Rel.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    echo $html;
}
```

header.php

```
<input type="button" value="Excel" id="Excel" name="Excel" onClick="javascript: List(4);" class="FlatDActv" onMouseOver="this.className='FlatActv';" onMouseOut="this.className='FlatDActv';" style="position: relative; width: 50">


function List(tp){

window.open('ranking.php?tp='+tp+'&cd_tipo='+document.getElementById('cd_tipo').value+'&dt_de='+document.getElementById('dt_de').value+'&dt_ate='+document.getElementById('dt_ate').value, "List");

}
```

Comment: Where is `$html` generated?  If it is, in fact, HTML (as the variable name indicates), then that's likely your problem.  The browser knows that, despite what your headers say, you're really sending a regular HTML document.

Comment: $html lists the results from db after download has started/finished

Comment: That really doesn't answer/address my question.  You should include the code that generates `$html`.  If you are not actually creating an XML document, you shouldn't tell your browser to expect one.

Comment: Sorry. My $html concatenates a big table with a lot of data and it is like $html .= "<table>"; $html .= "<tr>......"; $html .= "</table>";

Comment: the echo $html; lists that table after download

Comment: Okay, and that is _not_ a valid Excel document.  You need to research creating an Excel document in PHP.  Also, AFAIK, you can only set one Content-Type.  Only the last one will be recognized.  You should remove the second Content-Type header.

Comment: It works fine in other parts of my system just like it is in this example. And yes, I tried removing second Conten-type but it did not work. I think the frame is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just adding

```
if($tp==4){
    ob_clean();
}
```

before $html tags to clear the extra data when loading the file